# Testflight Crash troubleshooting

Tags: swift3, crash, testflight, crash-reports, xcode8

I have an app thats released to few users in testflight and there's been report of various crashes and most of them points to below crash log. I've not been able to reproduce the crash, so, I'm trying to identify where it could possibly cause crash through crash logs. Below is the crash log and the method where it points the crash.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001001c8e9c
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   My App                  0x00000001001c8e9c specialized MyTableViewController.didUpdateText(MyTableViewCell, withText : String) -> () + 1008 (MyTableViewController.swift:0)
1   My App                  0x00000001001c11b4 @objc MyTableViewController.didUpdateText(MyTableViewCell, withText : String) -> () + 92 (MyTableViewController.swift:0)
2   My App                  0x00000001001c1234 protocol witness for MyTableViewCellDelegate.didUpdateText(MyTableViewCell, withText : String) -> () in conformance MyTableViewController + 92 (MyTableViewController.swift:0)
3   My App                  0x00000001001f0550 specialized MyTableViewCell.textViewDidEndEditing(UITextView) -> () + 380 (MyTableViewCell.swift:225)
4   My App                  0x00000001001ef0cc @objc MyTableViewCell.textViewDidChange(UITextView) -> () + 52
5   UIKit                           0x00000001924a7ca0 -[UITextView resignFirstResponder] + 252 (UITextView.m:2151)
6   UIKit                           0x00000001924dc39c -[UITableView reloadData] + 328 (UITableView.m:5116)
7   My App                  0x00000001001bdcec MyTableViewController.loadDetailsView() -> () + 1040 (MyTableViewController.swift:220)
8   My App                  0x000000010017a4b0 MainViewController.loadDetailsView() -> () + 132 (MainViewController.swift:234)
9   My App                  0x000000010017a54c @objc MainViewController.loadDetailsView() -> () + 28 (MainViewController.swift:0)
10  My App                  0x00000001000edcbc __58-[DisplayViewController createNewInstanceForUser]_block_invoke + 120 (DisplayViewController.m:1221)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b18a9e0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:963)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b18a9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:473)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b18f5e8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 996 (inline_internal.h:2431)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c2810c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1793)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c27ece4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572 (CFRunLoop.c:3004)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c1aeda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
17  GraphicsServices                0x000000018dc19074 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
18  UIKit                           0x0000000192462c9c UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:4089)
19  My App                  0x000000010013f978 main + 92 (main.m:14)
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018b1bd59c start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2af224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2af09c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c280e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c27eae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c1aeda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
5   Foundation                      0x000000018ccc9db4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
6   Foundation                      0x000000018cceab84 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
7   UIKit                           0x0000000192dec830 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 (UIEventFetcher.m:313)
8   Foundation                      0x000000018cdc7318 __NSThread__start__ + 996 (NSThread.m:1163)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b39568c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b39559c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b392cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2af224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2af09c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c280e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c27eae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c1aeda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018c9bbdf4 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404 (NSURLConnection.mm:364)
6   Foundation                      0x000000018cdc7318 __NSThread__start__ + 996 (NSThread.m:1163)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b39568c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b39559c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b392cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2cce1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b394814 _pthread_cond_wait + 640 (pthread_cond.c:536)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018acbdac8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56 (condition_variable.cpp:44)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b5bf08 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 112 (condition_variable:202)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b5be7c bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 168 (condition_variable:211)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b5bd5c bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*) + 36 (AsyncTask.h:110)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b5c00c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 92 (__functional_base:416)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b39568c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b39559c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b392cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2af224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2af09c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c280e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c27eae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c1aeda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
5   WebCore                         0x0000000190e79d3c RunWebThread(void*) + 456 (WebCoreThread.mm:694)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b39568c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b39559c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b392cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2cce1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b394814 _pthread_cond_wait + 640 (pthread_cond.c:536)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001901af9a4 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 80 (ThreadingPthreads.cpp:359)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b42a68 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2256 (ParkingLot.cpp:597)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001907baf58 JSC::Heap::stopTheMutator() + 272 (ParkingLot.h:81)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001907b89a0 JSC::Heap::stopTheWorld() + 160 (Heap.cpp:1219)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001907ba230 JSC::Heap::collectInThread() + 192 (Heap.cpp:1118)
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001907bcd50 JSC::Heap::Thread::work() + 16 (Heap.cpp:229)
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b327f4 std::__1::__function::__func<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::Locker<WTF::LockBase> const&)::$_0, std::__1::allocator<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::Locker<WTF::LockBase> const&)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()() + 352 (AutomaticThread.cpp:215)
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001901abf7c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212 (functional:1817)
10  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001901abe8c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24 (ThreadingPthreads.cpp:164)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b39568c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b39559c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b392cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b392ca8 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread.c:2333)

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b392ca8 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread.c:2333)

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b392ca8 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread.c:2333)

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b392ca8 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread.c:2333)

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2cda88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b3931a4 _pthread_wqthread + 1260 (pthread.c:2205)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b392cac start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000000000000c   x1: 0x0000000176054d00   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x000000018b3132c0
    x4: 0x000000016fd72317   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000001   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x000000000000000b   x9: 0x0000000000000004  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0xbaddc0dedeadbead
   x12: 0x0000000174c73fb0  x13: 0x0000000000000010  x14: 0x0000000000000008  x15: 0x0000000000000010
   x16: 0x00000001010411f0  x17: 0x000000018ad530dc  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000176054d00
   x20: 0x0000000101340560  x21: 0x000000017644f810  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x00000001001bb5cc
   x24: 0x000000012a61f840  x25: 0x000000017569d150  x26: 0x0000000174243fa8  x27: 0x00000001003f5b30
   x28: 0x0000000100d31660   fp: 0x000000016fd726c0   lr: 0x00000001001c8c4c
    sp: 0x000000016fd72640   pc: 0x00000001001c8e9c cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Crash log in XCode points to this function

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    selectButton.isSelected = false
    selectButtonAction(true)
    delegate?.didUpdateText(self, withText: textView.text) //Crash points to this line
}
```

Since the delegate is optional I believe it shouldn't crash on this line, so if I put a nil check for delegate here I don't think it will do any good. Is there anyway to identify what could be causing the crash from this log?

Comment: `textView.text` is an implicitly unwrapped optional, so that's where I would start looking for the issue. If the function gets called when there's no input in the textView, it could cause the crash (even though the text might be _""_ and not `nil`).

Comment: @DávidPásztor, textViewDidEndEditing is a delegate method for textView, if its called, can it be nil?

Comment: I haven't said anywhere that the delegate would be nil... The `text` property of `textView` could be nil, you should check for that.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, by delegate I meant the textView delegate, what I meant was, if this textViewDidEndEditing gets called, is there a possibility that textView or its property text could be nil?

Comment: If `textView` is empty text property could be `nil`. But to solve this you can just put `textView.text ?? ""`